# Issues that are not actually created, after creating aws_vpc with the terraform 'apply' command

Tags: terraform, amazon-vpc

I'm a developer studying terraform.

I was practicing creating aws-vpc using terraform.

Executing the terraform `apply command` to see a message that the aws_vpc resource was `successful`

[image]

However, when checking the aws dashboard, I found an issue that was not generated (aws_vpc)

[image]

Is there anything I missed?

### Env & Result

This is the tf file used to create vpc

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "terraform-101"
  }
}
```

This is the terraform.tfstate (After terraform apply command)

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.3.6",
  "serial": 9,
  "lineage": "77523688-c1e9-2a45-7c9a-eaf2f866c290",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "aws_vpc",
      "name": "main",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 1,
          "attributes": {
            "arn": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-northeast-2:845502535698:vpc/vpc-016e5391ed5e5fb21",
            "assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block": false,
            "cidr_block": "10.0.0.0/16",
            "default_network_acl_id": "acl-0d138ce7c406b664f",
            
            ...

            "tags": {
              "Name": "terraform-101"
            },
            "tags_all": {
              "Name": "terraform-101"
            }
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [],
          "private": "~~~"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "check_results": null
}
```

I searched, but I couldn't find the right reason for the cause..

Comment: Your dashboard filter is set to display only one vpc.

Comment: You uploaded the wrong picture. Sorry.. Even if I turn off the actual filter, it is confirmed that there is only one vpc...

Comment: The screenshot showing the one VPC is actually the default VPC. Are you sure you are looking in the right AWS region?

Comment: The statefile says your VPC should be in `ap-northeast-2` (Seul). As was previously asked, are you sure you are looking in the right region from the console?

Comment: Really I was an idiot. The default vpc was east. Thank you for answer.